# Не работает увелечение span'a при наведении

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с фото, фото увеличивается, а вот спан который в нем - нет. Даже задал тот же класс и айди спану, все равно не работает (`<a><img><span></a>`  --- так выглядит структура).

```css
.column#zoomIn img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.column#zoomIn:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex mt-5">
  <a href="" class="column" id="zoomIn">
    <img src="./img/IMG_5345.JPG" alt="" class="w-56 border-2 border-gray-200"">
    <span id="zoomIn" class="column text-gray-500 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column" id="zoomIn">
    <img src="./img/IMG_5346.JPG" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200"">
    <span id="zoomIn" class="column text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column" id="zoomIn">
    <img src="./img/IMG_5347.JPG" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200"">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column" id="zoomIn">
    <img src="./img/IMG_5340.JPG" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200"">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Селектор `ID` в название должен иметь **уникальное** значение (единственным на странице) - [подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/id) (*htmlbook.ru - Идентификаторы*)
2. Используйте текстовый редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса **HTML** (да и любых языков)

```html
<!--  Лишняя кавычка, которая может ломать вёрстку при рендере браузером. ↓ -->
<img src="./img/IMG_5345.JPG" alt="" class="w-56 border-2 border-gray-200"">
```

3. Как сказал [@Enokin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1381752/221218):

> Чтобы `transform` работал необходимо назначить `display: inline-block;` на `span`

Но дополню, что помимо этого требуется добавить деформацию и на `span`, и ещё вешать только на первый `span` не трогая вложенные.

Результат:

```css
.flex {display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; width: 150px;}
.column {display: block;}
.column img {width: 30px;}

/* То что выше для теста */

.column img,
.column > span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.column > span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.column:hover img,
.column:hover > span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex mt-5">
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что результат всё же должен быть таким:

```css
.flex {display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; width: 150px;}
.column {display: block;}
.column img {width: 30px;}

/* То что выше для теста */

.column {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.column > span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.column:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex mt-5">
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="column">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/aJKHwHo.png" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200">
    <span class="text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, чем больше отвечаешь, тем сильнее развивается интуиция и телепатия (+) :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, скоро можно будет этот навык указывать в резюме))

Comment: @Daniil, всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы transform работал необходимо назначить `display: inline-block`; на span

```css
.column#zoomIn img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.column#zoomIn span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.column#zoomIn:hover img,
.column#zoomIn:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex mt-5">
  <a href="" class="column" id="zoomIn"><img src="https://see.news/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Space1.jpg" alt="" class="w-56 border-2 border-gray-200""><span id="zoomIn" class="column text-gray-500 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Странно, возможно, я выполнил что-то не так. Я сам думал тоже в этом ошибка, но вставил не тот фрагмент кода.                             <a href="" class="column" id="zoomIn"><img src="./img/IMG_5346.JPG" alt="" class="w-56 ml-7 border-2 border-gray-200""><span id="zoomIn" class="column text-gray-500 inline-block ml-7 bg-white px-4 py-2">В наличии:<span class="text-black"> 10</span></span></a>
Но попрежнему не работает

Comment: Ну я html код не менял только картинку добавил для наглядности, странно должно работать

Comment: Да уж, странность какая-то. Но, спасибо большое!